# Testing Sorting arrays

Tags: arrays, sorting

Hi I have problem with how to test my sort arrays. I have no problem in the coding of them however we are supposed to develop "smart" test cases. To test the sorting methods.

I dont get what the smart cases would be. I know if I was developing a calender a smart thest case would be the last day of the year etc. However I dont understand it for sorting.

The only thing I can think of would be the middle element the first and the last.

I dont want any code just some feedback on  what you thing smart cases would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to sort in increasing order:

1. a sorted array
2. an almost sorted array( only a few swaps would sort it )
3. a random array
4. an almost sorted array in decresing order
5. a sorted array in decreasing order

Afetr analising the performance on those, you could try:

1. random array with many duplicates

Answer (score 1):

If you're checking for **correctness**, you may want to try:

- a reversed order array: `[5,4,3,2,1]`
- a array with repeated elements `[1,1,3,3,2,2]`
- a array with *only* repeated elements `[1,1,1,1,1]`
- arrays with odd and even number of elements

If you're going to use associative arrays, you may want to check for [**stability**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_sort#Stability).

If you're checking for **runtime complexity**, you may also want to try longer arrays.